# Argue by duality that faithful functors also reflect epimorphisms.

Tags: category-theory

I'm working on Category Theory in Context, and I'm stuck on the second part of this problem.

[image]

i.e. Argue by duality that faithful functor also reflect epimorphisms.

My attempt:

So I will assume the first part. The most natural way seems to be to consider the contravariant and faithful functor $F: C^{op} \rightarrow D$. Suppose $F f^{op}$ is monomorphism. Then $f^{op} \in C^{op}$ is monomorphism. But this means that $f \in C$ is epimorphism.

Now, it seems if we prove that $F f$ is epimorphism, we would be done. But the problem is that what even would $F f$ be? Since $F$ is a functor from $C^{op}$ to $D$, $F f$ where $f \in C$ wouldn't even make any sense. So I'm stuck here.

Hints would be appreciated, and please note I'm looking to use duality here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** : consider a faithful functor $F$, and look at the same functor but viewed as a functor on opposite categories : $F^{op}: C^{op}\to D^{op}$. It's still faithful, and if $Ff$ is an epimorphism in $D$, then in $D^{op}$...

Comment: I assum $F^{op}$ is defined by $F^{op}(f^{op}) = (F(f))^{op}$? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it !